# Fail to install industrial_calibration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I'm trying to install industrial calibration and I therefore cloned the git repository into my catkin_ws and tried catkin_make.

I then got the following error:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openni2_camera"
  with any of the following names:

    openni2_cameraConfig.cmake
    openni2_camera-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "openni2_camera" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "openni2_camera_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "openni2_camera" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  industrial_calibration/rgbd_depth_correction/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'openni2_camera'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openni2_camera"
  with any of the following names:

    openni2_cameraConfig.cmake
    openni2_camera-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "openni2_camera" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "openni2_camera_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "openni2_camera" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  industrial_calibration/rgbd_depth_correction/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

so I tried to install openni2:

```
user@hyperchicken:~/catkin_ws/src$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni2-camera 
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-openni2-camera : Depends: libopenni2-0 but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libopenni2-dev but it is not going to be installed
 ros-indigo-ur-kinematics : Depends: ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I would be happy for any hint how to try fixing this problem.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253094/fail-to-install-industrial_calibration/) by [Beaucay](https://answers.ros.org/users/29173/beaucay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The following packages have unmet dependencies

This error is FAQ in lower level on Ubuntu, not ROS. I suggest you fix that by looking up one of many results from web search result ([e.g. Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=The+following+packages+have+unmet+dependencies%3A&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)).

Also suggested is how you not care if the dependency is met or not; see [this section in rosdep tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep#Install_dependency_of_all_packages_in_the_workspace) to automatically install ALL packages that the ROS packages in your workspace depend upon.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0